# OpenVPN client inside network can't ping with eachother

Tags: ping, openvpn

Everything looks configured well. From any client I can ping with 10.8.0.1(server), but can't reach other clients.

Here is my server.ovpn

```
port 1200

proto udp

dev tun

ca "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.key"

dh "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\config\\dh2048.pem"

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

keepalive 10 120

tls-auth "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 0 

cipher AES-256-CBC   # AES

comp-lzo

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

verb 3
```

And client.ovpn

```
client

dev tun

proto udp

remote AAAAAAA.eu 1200

resolv-retry infinite

nobind

persist-key
persist-tun

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\Karol-Komputer.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\Karol-Komputer.key"

tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 1

cipher AES-256-CBC

comp-lzo

verb 3
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, clients can only communicate with the server, not other clients. According to the manual's [section on configuration files](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#config), you can lift this restriction by adding the directive `client-to-client` to the server configuration.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work. I suppose that it could be because there is no default gateway set so packets doesn't know where to go.

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to change the default gateway, but your configuration isn't pushing routes; clients may not have them. Add 10.8.0.0/24 to the route table and make sure the server OS is routing packets (`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TcpIp\Parameters\IpEnableRouter`). Check whether firewalls are blocking ICMP echo requests.